# Bubble-Sort not sorting in C (Cormen's pseudocode)

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

So I was trying to implement [Cormen's pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD4hi.png) for bubble sorting but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is my approach on Cormen's pseudocode:

```
void BUBBLE_SORT(int a[200], int n) {
    int i, j, aux;

    for (i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        for (j = n; j < i + 1; j++) {
            if (a[j] < a[j - 1]) {
                aux = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried another piece of code found on the internet but the result was not different:

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) {
    int i, j;     
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)          
        for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)  
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) 
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);  
}
```

I would love to know where my comprehension failed in understanding Cormen's implementation and to get the bubble sorting to work!

Comment: It doesn't look correct, in your if condition you are comparing a[j] with a[j-1] but swapping a[j] with a[j+1] should the swap also be the same as the condition ?

Comment: `for(j=n;j<i+1;` - If `j = n` and `i < n`, how can `j` be smaller than `i`? Your inner loop makes no sense.

Comment: Well, I thought so too. But doesn't the pseudocode say that? I mean line 2: j=a.length.

By the way, what 'downto' refers to? "<"?

Comment: @pustiul500 It means the loop counts down instead of up. Instead of incrementing the loop variable after each iteration, it decrements it, and the target value is not an upper bound, but a lower bound. For example, `for i = 1 to 10` counts from 1 to 10 (1, 2, 3, ...), but `for i = 10 downto 1` counts from 10 down to 1 (10, 9, 8, ...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least three issues:

1. The pseudocode assumes array indices go from `1` to `length`. In C arrays are indexed from `0` to `length-1`; your code doesn't correct for that.
2. The inner loop in the pseudocode goes *`downto`* `i+1`, but your inner loop tries to count *up*:

   ```
   for(j=n;j<i+1;j++)
   ```

   should be

   ```
   for (j = n; j > i; j--)
   ```
3. The pseudocode swaps `A[j]` and `A[j-1]`, but your C code swaps `A[j]` and `A[j+1]`.

Comment: As far as I know, Cormen is starting all his for's from 1, ignoring 0.

I made the changes suggested by you, altough I let the for starting from 1, and it know works.

One question, if you please: Did I intrerpretate the pseudocode correctly? If so, why it didn't work and instead of "j<i+1;j++" the correct code is "j>i;j--"?

Comment: No, pustiul, it __won't__ work when starting from 1. The example uses arrays `1..n` but, as said, C arrays are `0..n-1`. Don't try to be clever; just try to learn.

Comment: @pustiul500, you did not interpret the pseudo code correctly, In particular, you changed the word _downto_ to _upto_ (Melpomene's 2nd comment).

Comment: I do try to learn. But this is the way we were teached the whole semester, to start for's from 1, based on Cormen's book, in order to not confuse us later on.

I'll revise everything again and try to look at it from another angle.

Answer (score 1):

Mistakes in your implementation:

1. You start counting your array from 1th index. But in C programing a array start with 0th position. [you should right i = 0 instead of i = 1]
2. The inner loop must run from ***j = n-1*** from ***j = i+1*** and the value of ***j*** must be decreasing.
3. You compare  ***a[j]*** with ***a[j-1]*** but u swap ***a[j]*** with ***a[j+1]***. you should have swap ***a[j]*** with ***a[j-1]***

See the changes in the code below. Hope it will be useful:

```
int i, j, aux;
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    for(j=n-1;j>=i+1;j--){
        if(a[j]<a[j-1]){
            aux=a[j];
            a[j]=a[j-1];
            a[j-1]=aux;
        }
    }
}
```